# How to keep the original phi command with another name?

Tags: greek, renewcommand

Since I don't usually use the "original" phi I have the following code in my preamble:

```latex
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}
```

However, I'm now in a situation where I really need the "original" phi so I tried the following:

```latex
\newcommand{\phialt}{\phi}
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}
```

I was hoping that defining `\phialt` before redefining `\phi` would work but it doesn't. Is there a way I can achieve something like this? I want to keep the φ for `\phi` and have another command for the "original".

Comment: \NewCommandCopy\phialt\phi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually `\phi` and `\varphi` are defined with `\DeclareMathSymbol`, so

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\phialt=\phi
  \mathchardef\phi=\varphi
}
```

would do. At begin document because packages might change the setup.

However, to be on the safe side and to not depend on the internal implementation, I'd recommend

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\phialt}{\phi}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\phi}{\varphi}%
}
```